# Switch image on hover

Tags: jquery

Please see [this reference URL](http://www.deanelliott.me/graphictankclients/nyce/roster/michonne-brown/) to get a better idea of what I mean, I'm rubbish at describing things.

Basically, as you can ese, there is one "main" image and 5 "thumb" images. What my client wants is for the "main" image to change everytime someone hovers over one of the "thumb" images.

So, for example, if someone hovered over the third thumb, the main image would change to the full size version of that thumb...

Does that make sense?

I'm using Wordpress so I don't know if anyone knows of a plugin that does something similar.

Comment: If there isn't a plugin, you can just give the thumbnails `onmouseover="thatimage.src='newsource.jpg'"` attributes. Doesn't really need a jQuery solution.

Comment: Bind http://api.jquery.com/hover/ to each of the smaller images. Refer the source of the small image (and their big variant) to be the CSS background for the big version. Pretty basic jQuery. Maybe hire someone with more knowledge about it? :)

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle or codepen of your problem. That reference link, while not absolutely NSFW might be described as "potentially awkward for work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do something like this?

```
$('.thumb').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#main').attr('src' , $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: How would that work with this code? [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oDcfA). Sorry, jQuery isn't my strong suit at all